# How to change folder hierarchy while migrating project from VSS to GITLAB

Tags: gitlab, visual-sourcesafe

I am trying to migrating project from VSS to GITLAB. I am using VSS2GIT for importing project from VSS to local file. Here are the folder structure once I import successfully.!

[image]

Now I am pushing this project to GITLAB using following command
    `git push -u origin master`

It push project successfully.
[image]
My problem is, I don't want this hierarchy of the folder structure.

```
/2010/Betty.root/Betty
```

Instead I want all files under just single Betty.root or Betty folder

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way - move files to correct locations, commit and push.

More complex way - use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch for rewrite history and then push it to gitlab with option 'force'